# Migrating Drupal

Tags: drupal

Currently I have a single drupal site installed on apache 2.2 with php 5.3 on RHEL 6. I am moving servers and am trying to migrate the site. I have imported the database and htaccess, but I cannot access any of the pages other than the root of the site.

Comment: Sounds like mod_rewrite isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to disable clean URLs before exporting the database, try to add `?q=` before each path.

Answer (score 1):

That happens when:

a) Apache mod_rewrite is not enabled. If you have root access then do `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

or

b) .htaccess file at the root folder isn't there, so you need to copy it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a troubleshoot check list for `mod_rewrite` issues:

- Make sure Apache's rewrite module is enabled:  `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.
- Make sure original `.htaccess` file is there in the root of your Drupal installation.
- Make sure that the existing `.htaccess` file is getting read by Apache. To test it, add a this line in the beginning of the file and you should get a **500 Internal Server Error**: `ThisIsReallyABadSyntax`.
- If the `.htaccess` file is not in effect, make sure that the `AllowOverride` directive in the main Apache config file (usually `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` on debian-based distros) is set to `All`. It might be set to `None` by default.
- Finally, make sure that the clean URLs feature is enabled in Drupal settings.

Answer (score 0):

With the ***phpinfo();*** compare all the server specs, just to be sure both server are quite the same or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to migrate Drupal correctly:

1. Go to Configuration
2. find Clean URLs
3. Disable tick inside!
4. Clean cache!
5. Download your site file
6. Download your database
7. Create new database in your new site
8. Transfer file and database
9. Log in
   10.Do this step to enable Clean URLs:

It's work 100% guaranteed !

Steps:
1. Download - Dev version (7.x-dev)
2. Find file .htaccess
3. just copy it to your server
4. That's it !